# CSS responsive layout without repeating HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to create an HTML-CSS layout with 3 divs and I am trying to think what is the best way to write minimal HTML which would help me achieve something like this: [image]

I can achieve this using flexbox but only if I repeat HTML for div no. 3 and change `order` property of div no. 2.
What might be the optimal solution without repeating any HTML code i.e. writing something like

```
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
```

and not repeating any HTML but only writing optimal CSS such that it behaves the same way as in the screenshot?

Comment: You can utilize grid layout here + a media query for re-ordering the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a good start using [CSS Grid Template Areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

See snippet below to match your screenshot.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container>div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "one one two two" "three three two two" ". . two two";
    gap: 20px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .container>div {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .one {
    grid-area: one;
  }
  .two {
    grid-area: two;
  }
  .three {
    grid-area: three;
  }
}


/*For styling*/

.container>div {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```